# Error displaying a linked image on a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, tiles

I have a java web app running as a standalone using embedded jetty.  It works exactly as expected when run on a Mac OS X with Java 7.  However, when run using the same launch command on Windows 7 with Java 7, one of the JSP pages has a problem.  Here is the relevant part of the JSP page:

```
<nested:notEmpty property="filesList">
    <nested:iterate property="filesList" indexId="i">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <nested:write property="name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <nested:write property="description"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:viewHydrationFile('hydrationOperations(<%=operationName%>).filesList[<%=i%>]','show-hydration-file-content_<%=ind%>_<%=i%>','to-reload');" id="show-hydration-file-content_<%=ind%>_<%=i%>">Show</a>
                <nested:link action="/my-files/downloadHydrationFile.do" property="linkParameters">Export</nested:link>
                <nested:hidden property="viewContent" />
                <nested:equal property="viewContent" value="true">    
                    <nested:equal property="type" value="poredist">
                        <nested:define id="poredistName" property="poredistName" />
                        <div id="hydration-file-content_<%=ind%>_<%=i%>" class="to-reload file-poredist"><img src="/vcctl/image/<%=poredistName%>" /></div>
                    </nested:equal>
                   <nested:equal property="type" value="image">
                        <nested:define id="sliceName" property="sliceName" />
                        <div id="hydration-file-content_<%=ind%>_<%=i%>" class="to-reload file-image"><nested:link action="/my-files/viewImage.do" target="_blank" property="linkParameters"><img src="/vcctl/image/<%=sliceName%>" /></nested:link></div>
                    </nested:equal>
                </nested:equal>
                <nested:equal property="viewContent" value="false">
                    <nested:equal property="type" value="poredist">
                       <div id="hydration-file-content_<%=ind%>_<%=i%>" class="to-reload file-poredist"></div>
                   </nested:equal>
                   <nested:equal property="type" value="image">
                       <div id="hydration-file-content_<%=ind%>_<%=i%>" class="to-reload file-image"></div>
                   </nested:equal>
               </nested:equal>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </nested:iterate>
</nested:notEmpty>
```

I realize there is a javascript function call here, but it is pretty generic, making a call to a java Action that fetches the png image.  I will be happy to post both the javascript function and the java Action if that would be helpful.

The section for "image" files works fine even on Windows.  It will display the image, and I can hide it and then redisplay it as expected.  The problem is with the "poredist" section, which will display the correct png image one time, with the following message on the java console:

```
INFO: Tiles process complete; forward to /my-files/my-hydration-files.jsp
Apr 11, 2014 10:30:03 AM org.apache.struts.tiles.commands.TilesPreProcessor exec
ute
```

However, if I then hide this png file and attempt to display it again, the image is broken and the following message is displayed on the console:

```
INFO: Tiles process complete; forward to /my-files/my-hydration-files.jsp
C:\Users\bullard\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-vcctl.war-_vcctl-any-4877
14299336733721.dir\webapp\image\HydrationOf-TestPaste.img.25.000.poredist.png (T
he requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section
open)
```

I don't understand this last error and cannot find much about it with a web search.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you are forgetting to close an input stream or related resource when you read the file the first time?

Comment: While examining the java Action code to make the file, I realized that I was trying to delete the file if it already existed and then remake it.  I removed that check, so now it just returns the file name if it already exists, and that fixed the problem.  Don't know why that worked on Mac but not on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java code responsible for making the file was trying to delete the file if it already existed and then remake it.  The error occurred right at the point where the file just deleted was attempting to reopen as a new file.  Modifying the java to simply return the file name if it already exists fixes the problem and I think is better coding practice anyway.

As to why it worked on Mac before but not on Windows, the following post on yahoo provides an answer:  https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090927164148AAOdJmE